# Change stop condition during Parrallel For loop

Tags: c#, list, parallel-processing, parallel.for

I want to explore in parallel some locations. In Master Thread before parallel loop, I explored first location and I have new locations to explore (for example 50 new locations). But I want to explore 100 locations (if there is so many new locations), so I have to change stop condition of loop.

```
Parallel.For(1, Locations.Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
    (index, state) =>
    {

          var newLocations = FindSomethingInLocation(Locations[index])
          locationsInIndex(index, newLocations) // -> dictionary
          if(Locations.Count < 100)
          {
              Locations.Add(newLocations)
          }

    }
```

I want to explore 100 locations and get elements for every of explored location.

How can I do that during. It is possible? Currently I am doing something as on example above, but if Locations have 50 elements on start of loop. Loop will explore only 50 locations, even when I increasing Locations list with new elements, stop condition did not change.

Maybe someone has got better idea for this solution?

And some other question about that. Do you know how Parallel.For is scheduling iterations? Do main thread divide problem into N Threads at the start? Or do it more dynamically - when thread finish some iteration, it gets some new work from main thread?

Thank you all!

Comment: You can't change the condition, as the dataset has already been partitioned and assigned to the threads (Though you *can* cause the other threads to *stop* executing).  I would consider queueing up additional work to complete after the initial search has been done.  `Parallel` just uses `ThreadPool` threads.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've changed that code. 
I've moved the parallel loop to the method and I'm calling that from while loop with "dynamic" condition. It seems to be working. This solution causes synchronizing threads after every calling method with a parallel loop, but in my case, it will happen only a few times, and because every thread has got similar work to do, synchronizing does not cost ver much.